# Recuperate Non inserted rows Oracle

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have 10.000 rows to insert into a table.

For an Insert With FORALL in oracle...

```
FORALL x IN TABLE_NAME.First .. TABLE_NAME.Last
  INSERT
  INTO TABLE_NAME VALUES
    (
      TABLE_NAME(x).VAL1,
      TABLE_NAME(x).VAL2,
      TABLE_NAME(x).VAL3,
      TABLE_NAME(x).VAL4,
      TABLE_NAME(x).VAL5
    );
```

How can I recover the data from rows that doesnt insert into table due violation of constrainst in order to insert those items in a non-typed table of rejected items?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`save exceptions` clause of the `forall` statement](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/forall_statement.htm) to collect the error(s), and then use [the `sql%bulk_exceptions` implicit cursor attribute](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/sql_cursor.htm#LNPLS1213) to see what actually happened. There's [an example](https://docs.oracle.com/cloud/latest/db112/LNPLS/tuning.htm#BABGBABA) in that documentation, but in your case you can do (using a made up table and data):

```
create table your_table (val1 number primary key, val2 number, val3 number, val4 number, val5 number);

declare
  type l_table_type is table of your_table%rowtype;
  l_table l_table_type := l_table_type();

  dml_errors exception;
  pragma exception_init(dml_errors, -24381);
begin
  l_table.extend;
  l_table(l_table.count).val1 := 1;
  l_table(l_table.count).val2 := 1.2;
  l_table(l_table.count).val3 := 1.3;
  l_table(l_table.count).val4 := 1.4;
  l_table(l_table.count).val5 := 1.5;

  l_table.extend;
  l_table(l_table.count).val1 := 2;
  l_table(l_table.count).val2 := 2.2;
  l_table(l_table.count).val3 := 2.3;
  l_table(l_table.count).val4 := 2.4;
  l_table(l_table.count).val5 := 2.5;

  l_table.extend;
  l_table(l_table.count).val1 := 1;
  l_table(l_table.count).val2 := 3.2;
  l_table(l_table.count).val3 := 3.3;
  l_table(l_table.count).val4 := 3.4;
  l_table(l_table.count).val5 := 3.5;

  forall x in l_table.first .. l_table.last save exceptions
    insert
    into your_table values
      (
        l_table(x).val1,
        l_table(x).val2,
        l_table(x).val3,
        l_table(x).val4,
        l_table(x).val5
      );

exception
  when dml_errors then
    for i in 1..sql%bulk_exceptions.count loop
      dbms_output.put_line('Index ' || sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index
        || ' error ' || -sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_code);
      dbms_output.put_line(' val1: ' || l_table(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index).val1);
      dbms_output.put_line(' val2: ' || l_table(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index).val2);
      dbms_output.put_line(' val3: ' || l_table(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index).val3);
      dbms_output.put_line(' val4: ' || l_table(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index).val4);
      dbms_output.put_line(' val5: ' || l_table(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index).val5);
    end loop;
end;
/
```

That produces the output:

```
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

Index 3 error -1
 val1: 1
 val2: 3.2
 val3: 3.3
 val4: 3.4
 val5: 3.5
```

The first collection element with `val1` set to one was inserted successfully; the second one got the unique constraint exception and was not - but it was put into the bulk exception mechanism instead of causing the entire statement to fail.

You can then decide whether to raise an exception (or re-raise), or immediately roll back (possibly to a savepoint); or commit the inserts that did not error.

You can also insert the same values into your table of rejected items, but you'd need to be a bit careful if you're rolling back other changes (presumably you wouldn't be in that scenario though).

You can't directly use another `forall` to do that - referring to `l_table(sql%bulk_exceptions(i).error_index).val1` inside the `values()` clause throws ORA-00911 because of the `%` character - so you'd either have to do individual inserts inside the `for` loop, or copy the values to another collection and bulk-insert from that. Unless you are expecting a lot of rejections individual inserts might be good enough.